# Adding new Resources in Azure Resource Group Project

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, cloud, azure-resource-manager

I would like to develop an ARM-Template in Visual Studio 2017. First, I choose  **Azure Resource Group**:

[image: New Project: Azure Resource Group]

Then I choose **Blank Template**:

[image: Select Azure Template: Blank Template]

Then I would like to choose some resources, for example, DataFactory, DataLake, Databricks, and....
So I right click on **resources** --> **Add new Resource**, but as you can see I have only a limited number of resources (no DataFactory, no DataLake...).

[image: Add Resource]

Do you have any idea how can I add another resources in this window of Visual Studio?

Comment: i dont think you can, but since its just json, you can just copy paste them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this quick resource addition in VS for commonly use resources.If above resource is not available in quick addition you need to create those resources manually. You can add templates from [azure github template gallery](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates).